# Suppress Logger when testing

Tags: testing, logging, elixir

I wonder how to disable logging in Elixir when testing. In my current code I test for logger messages, so I don't want to disable it completely, but hide the messages until any test stop passing.

I'm using mix and ExUnit to manage and test my project.

```
mix test
Compiling 2 files (.ex)
.........
17:59:18.446 [warn]  Code seems to be empty
.
17:59:18.447 [warn]  Code doesn't contain HLT opcode
.
17:59:18.448 [warn]  Code doesn't contain HLT opcode

17:59:18.448 [error] Label error doesn't exist
.....

Finished in 0.07 seconds
16 tests, 0 failures
```

Answer (score 29):

Either use `ExUnit.CaptureLog`:

```rb
import ExUnit.CaptureLog

test "example" do
   assert capture_log(fn ->
      Logger.error "log msg"
   end) =~ "log msg"
end
```

Or if you just want to ignore any logs then:

```rb
@tag capture_log: true
test "example" do
    Logger.error "log msg"
end
```

Comment: This answer is perfect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Into your `config/test.exs` file put the following config for the logger:

```rb
config :logger, level: :error
```

If you don’t have environment-specific configs, put the following line in your `config/config.exs`:

```rb
config :logger, level:
  case Mix.env do
    :test -> :error
    _ -> :info
  end
```

---

Another option would be to use another backend for the logging messages (assuming `{:logger_file_backend, "~> 0.0"}` is included in `deps` section of `mix.exs`):

```rb
config :logger,
  compile_time_purge_level: :debug,
  format: "$date $time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  metadata: [:application, :module, :function, :file, :line],
  backends: [{LoggerFileBackend, :info_warn_error}]

config :logger, :info_warn_error,
  path: "log/info_warn_error.log", # or "/dev/null"
  level: :warn
```

Comment: I didn't mention, but I tried using first way and it preserved error, plus tests based on warning stopped passing. Second way is more or less the same thing, so I'll try adding own backend or just leave it as it is. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Having the only backend with path `/dev/null` does _exactly_ what you want: it suppresses any output to everywhere (including console,) but it leaves the logger’s `gen_event` server alive, so you can test whatever you want. _Sidenote:_ I find it strange you want to suppress errors.

Comment: Well, I think this isn't strange when you start testing for errors. If you write like 10-15 tests for it, it becomes really annoying to see this all error messages, which are expected to appear.

Comment: This post is a few years old and not exactly the same context, but Jose Valim recommends setting to error: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/898

Answer (score 7):

I spotted `remove_backend()` function in Logger's docs, so after using 
`Logger.remove_backend(:console)`
in file where Logger should be disabled, every logged message is gone (tests are passing by the way).

EDIT: I asked Logger devs this question. Apparently, it's better to use `@moduletag :capture_log` on top of the test than removing backend. Anyway, works, so fine for me.

Comment: Probably not the best idea.  You're removing any logging at all--test run or otherwise.  You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly for what I was looking.